# How to increase the memory for the job history server

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

Job History server is going out of memory when trying to load the task status after the job completed. We are trying to increase the memory for the job history server. Any idea how we can increase the XMX for the job history server? I am Apache Hadoop 2.4.0 and running YARN.

Answer (score 0):

Restart the history server with the following settings:

HADOOP_JOB_HISTORYSERVER_HEAPSIZE=5 bash -x  bin/mapred --config /Users/ajaymysore/gitHome/proton/resources/hadoop/conf historyserver

Note that 5 is the amount of memory you want to allocate in MB.